# Taylor Series, exponential function

Tags: calculus

Determine the derivative $f^2(0)$ of the function $\dfrac{(e^x-1)}x$.

I am really lost when figuring out the answer to this question. I have found the Taylor series for the function:
$1 + \dfrac1{2x} + \dfrac1{6x^2} + \dfrac1{24x^3}+\dots$

Even though I am not sure, why this is true...
I don't have a good approach to these kind of problems, so I hope someone can explain it to me :)

Comment: You don't really need taylor series. Use the product rule of derivatives for $(e^x -1) \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Well for the second derivative, I get: e^x/x - 2e^x/x^2 - 2(e^x-1)/x^3, but then for f^(2)(0), I'll just get zero, right?

Comment: That's not a Taylor series...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ve probably typed wrongly the taylor series.
The correct taylor series is: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n} {(n+1)!}$$.This series has 0 as center of the series.
Using sum of power series’s property you can say that $$ f^{k} (0) = \frac{k!}{k+1!} $$.
Thus $$f^{2} (0) = \frac{2}{6}$$.

You can also solve this problem noticing that 0 is not an element of the domain of f and every derivative . Neverthless you can define the function in 0 for continuity.
So $$ f^2 (0) = \lim_{x\to 0} f^{2} (x)$$ .
You will obtain the same result.

I hope to have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+\cdots$$
$$e^x-1=x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+\cdots$$
$$\frac{e^x-1}x=1+\frac{x}2+\frac{x^2}6+\cdots$$
$$\frac d{dx}\frac{e^x-1}x=\frac12+\frac{x}3+\cdots$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{e^x-1}x=\frac13+\cdots$$